# Erroneous query works when used as subquery - how? Why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, subquery, sql-server-2000

Let's consider two tables:

- MY_DB.dbo.MY_TABLE1 that **does** contain column MY_PROBLEMATIC_COLUMN
- MY_DB.dbo.MY_TABLE2 that does **not** contain column MY_PROBLEMATIC_COLUMN

As expected, *query1*:

```
SELECT MY_PROBLEMATIC_COLUMN 
FROM MY_DB.dbo.MY_TABLE2
```

Results with:

```
Server: Msg 207, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
Invalid column name 'MY_PROBLEMATIC_COLUMN'.
```

However, this *query2*, which uses *query1* as a subquery, works:

```
SELECT *
FROM MY_DB.dbo.MY_TABLE1 t1
WHERE t1.MY_PROBLEMATIC_COLUMN IN (
            SELECT MY_PROBLEMATIC_COLUMN 
            FROM MY_DB.dbo.MY_TABLE2
            )
```

And returns **all** rows from MY_DB.dbo.MY_TABLE.

How is it that erroneous is evaluated when used as subquery?

I don't believe it's crucial, but for a matter of fact, MY_PROBLEMATIC_COLUMN is of type varchar(50).

My first guess was that for some reason subquery is evaluated to NULL, yet then *query2* would return 0 rows, as  in NULL evaluates to false (I believe?)

DBMS: Sql Server 2000 (Sad, I know...)

Comment: This is essentially a correlated subquery (but without the correlation!)

Comment: I.e. the column MY_PROBLEMATIC_COLUMN in the sub-select belongs to MY_TABLE1... Qualify both versions (MY_TABLE1.MY_PROBLEMATIC_COLUMN and MY_TABLE2.MY_PROBLEMATIC_COLUMN) and you'll see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Always* use table aliases, especially with correlated subqueries.  You think your query is:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM MY_DB.dbo.MY_TABLE1 t1
WHERE t1.MY_PROBLEMATIC_COLUMN IN (
            SELECT t2.MY_PROBLEMATIC_COLUMN 
            FROM MY_DB.dbo.MY_TABLE2 t2
            )
```

But, because `t2.MY_PROBLEMATIC_COLUMN` does not exist, SQL avoids an error and looks for a column in an outer scope.  The query is interpreted as:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM MY_DB.dbo.MY_TABLE1 t1
WHERE t1.MY_PROBLEMATIC_COLUMN IN (
            SELECT t1.MY_PROBLEMATIC_COLUMN 
            FROM MY_DB.dbo.MY_TABLE2 t2
            )
```

This will return all non-NULL values in `t1` -- assuming that `t2` has at least one row.  Otherwise, nothing will be returned.

Note:  this is ANSI standard behavior and not specific to a single database.

Comment: Whoa, that explains everything. Could you explain how inner query is evaluated in more details? Does it return all rows from t1 for each row of t2? Similar to join query without ON condition or cross join? If so: why NULL values in t1 are omitted?

Comment: @browning0 . . . In SQL Server, a `where` clause can never increase the number of rows returned by a query.  It is used for filtering the result set.  (This is not true in all databases.)  So, your query can only return rows from `t1`.